# Joining two tables and display data from first table

Tags: sql

I have two tables tblPatient, tblDropDowns
tblpatient:

```
firstname   gender  patienttype
anil         1           3
Satheesh     1           4
Vinod        1           4 
Shashikanth  1           3
Srimani      2           3
Thanuja      2           4
Nandini      2           4
Vishu        2           3
```

and 
tblDropdowns:

```
id  Name
1   Male
2   Female
3   Inpatient
4   Outpatient
```

Now i want to display the patient table with gender and patient type as their significant names are connected to dropdown table.
result table:

```
firstname          gender       patienttype
anil                male         inpatient
satheesh            male         outpatient
vinod               male          outpatient
```

please help me out..
thanks 
anil

Comment: That can be accomplish using simple joins. That's basic SQL. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

In general it would be better avoid storing different things in the same table. However, you could join with subqueries that only contain the relevant records.

```
SELECT firstname, gender.Name AS gender, patienttype.Name As patienttype
FROM tblPatient p
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, Name 
            FROM tblDropdowns
            WHERE id IN (1, 2)) gender 
ON p.gender = gender.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, Name
            FROM tblDropdowns
            WHERE id > 2) patienttype
ON p.patienttype = patienttype.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try out this.

```
select [column1], [column2] from tblpatient a, tbldropdowns b
where a.gender = b.id order by a.gender;
```

You could also use joins: Please refer [this W3Schools SQL Link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Hope this helps. Thanks.

**Edit**
Maybe this query could be your solution:

```
    select a.firstname, b.name as 'gender', b.name as 'PatientType' 
    from tblpatient a, tbldropdowns b
    where a.gender = b.id and a.patienttype = b.id
    order by a.gender;
```

Thanks again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

```
 SELECT firstname, name, CASE WHEN (patienttype=3) THEN 'inpatient' ELSE 'outpatient' END as patienttype_text from tblpatient INNER JOIN tbldropdowns ON gender = id
```

Answer (score -1):

join your  "tblDropdowns" table twice in your select query.

Please refer this link to understand join,
 http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

```
select     tP.firstname,tG.Name gender,tPT.Name patienttype 
from       tblPatient tP 
left join  tblDropDowns tG 
on tG.id  = tP.gender 
left join  tblDropDowns tPT 
on tPT.id = tP.patienttype
```

Comment: Really I don't know guys, why the negative is,    
   
    _**select     tP.firstname,tG.Name gender,tPT.Name patienttype
    from       tblPatient tP
    left join  tblDropDowns tG
    on tG.id  = tP.gender  
    left join  tblDropDowns tPT
    on tPT.id = tP.patienttype**_  

Is it not possible?